# How to get designtime text visible in a multi-language application in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization

I have a WPF application where I'm using resource files to make it multi-language.

Like this:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var lang = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Languages/" + Settings.Default.Language + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = lang });
    }
    catch
    {
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("..\\Languages\\English.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
    }
}
```

So, for any labels that display text, I set them like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource DYouKnow}"/>
```

This works great at runtime but at design time I don't see my default text on my labels, which makes it difficult to design/maintain the UI.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question and removed the code snippets tags, because you provide a [tag:c#] code sample and not a [tag:html] code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a MarkupExtension, you can create an extension you can use in your XAML which will provide design-time text as well.

You can use it as follows:

```
<TextBlock loc:TranslateExtension.Key="txtTextKey" Text="{loc:TranslateExtension Default='Default text'}" />
```

See the following tutorial:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/localizemarkupextension.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your View constructor after the `InitializeComponent()` call:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
     this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("..\\Languages\\English.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) })
```

..with the XAML URI adjusted to the particular folder location of the current View file.